# MVC Model is null after calling RedirectToAction

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm experiencing a NullReferenceException when I attempt a **RedirectToAction** after completing a POST Action. Here is a summary of what I'm attempting:

After an Application is POST'ed, if the Application is valid I want the client redirected to another **View** (*and **Route***) for follow-on processes.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SubmitApplication(Application application)
{
    // Do stuff

    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return View(application);
    }

    // Create and set variables for the next route

    return RedirectToAction("ApplicationReview", new
    {
        x = "foo",
        y = "bob"
    });
}

[HttpGet]
public ActionResult ApplicationReview(string x, string y)
{
    // Do stuff using x and y as keys

    return View();
}
```

In the **SubmitApplication** View I have code similar to the following, although it is more elaborate. After the **RedirectToAction** is called the **Model** object in the **SubmitApplication** View is null and throws an exception. I can sort-of understand why the **SubmitApplication** View is returned as part of the redirect process, I just can't figure out why the Model is null or how to set it. In the end, the target Action is never reached presumably because the redirect never really occured.

```
@if (Model.HasSomething)
{ 
    ...
}
```

What am I doing wrong? Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second parameter in RedirectToAction is not for the model, but for the routeValues.

To maintain state temporarily for a redirect result, you need to store your data in TempData.

Comment: Be aware, if you use TempData, and the user refreshes the page somehow (say F5) the TempData items will be gone.  This is why I find TempData to be the most worthless thing in MVC and should never be used except in very rare situations.  So rare, that I can't even think of a reason to use it in which this problem won't exist.

Comment: By the way, the route values will add the values to the querysring (if they are not defined in a route) so they will be bound to the parameter list of the called action.

Comment: @MystereMan: I think TempData is useful when you do a Post-Redirect-Get and need to send some data to the destination action.

Comment: No, it's not.  Again, if you refresh the page after the get, the data you sent in TempData is gone so a refresh will not have the state you sent in TempData.  It works, but will be unreliable.

Comment: @Tuan I understand, I was attempting to pass in the values that are needed for the target route and not the Model. Then again, I suppose I could be doing that wrong as well

Answer (score 0):

It's a little unclear to me what you mean when you say `After the RedirectToAction is called the Model object is null and throws an exception.`, because in the code you show you don't do anything with the Model after you call RedirectToAction.

Do you mean the Model is null in your ApplicationReview view?

EDIT:

A null reference exception indicates that variable is being dereferenced.  There is nothing there that dereferences the model.  Perhaps if you posted the stack track it would help.

Comment: Sorry for not being more clear. The exception is thrown in the **SubmitApplication** View after the execution of the **SubmitApplication** Action Method. As far as I can tell, the **ApplicationReview** Action is never actually called so the associated View is never rendered.